# Fedex API using c# get rates for freight, why am I getting an error

Tags: c#, api, fedex

I downloaded sample code from the Fedex site in order to call an api in order to get rate for a specific freight.  The program is RateWebServiceClient.

I created test credentials and entered in the test key, password, account number, and meter number.  The service url is https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services/rate.  When I call the service.GetRates by passing in the RateRequest object, I get the following exception:

The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.

I then created production credentials and changed the key, password, account number and meter number and I changed the service url to https://ws.fedex.com:443/web-services/rate.  Now I get the following  SoapException:

UnrecoverableClientErrorSchemaErrorvalidation failure for RateRequest Error:cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'RateRequest'.

I'm not sure what I am missing or if I am possibly calling the incorrect web service url or something else.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use do this in C#:

```
using System.Security.Authentication;
```

Create 2 constants:

```
public const SslProtocols _Tls12 = (SslProtocols)0x00000C00;
public const SecurityProtocolType Tls12 = (SecurityProtocolType)_Tls12;
```

Use like this :

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Tls12;
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#,

```
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Net;

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```